# SQL query to get a result divided by 2

Tags: sql

Given a table with column like city and cityId,Adderesses. How would i write a query that gives a list cities where cityID is only even numbers. Plz explain in details.

Comment: Please tag dbms used. (You've already got one product specific answer...)

Answer (score 8):

Use the [modulo operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod)

```
select * from your_table
where mod(cityID, 2) = 0
```

Comment: `%` is product specific (and no dbms tagged). `MOD(cityID, 2)` is the ANSI SQL way.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect whether a number is even with the module operator (`%`), which gives the remainder after division by 2:

```
select * from your_table where cityID % 2= 0
```

The above query will give all the rows in which the cityID is divisible by 2

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in mod then it would be
select  6%2  -- results for this is 0
if you would want to select a number divided by 2 it will always return 0 for the perfect devisors.
if want the division  the use the normal / operator as below
eg select 6/3

Answer (score 0):

I used a slightly different approach. this is an event if you want  a result of a zero or 1 if perfect divisor and zero otherwise
So my script is something like this

```
select case when @value<2 then 0 when  @value%2 =0 then 1 else 0  end as myresult;
```

An example is as below for validating numbers between 1 and 20. You could amend it to fit your purpose

```
begin
declare @a int,@b int
set @a=1;
set @b = 20
while @a<=@b
begin
declare @value int
set @value =@a
select @value as myval, case when @value<2 then 0 when  @value%2 =0 then 1 else 0  end 
as myresult;
set @a=@a+1;
end
end
```